# How to manage the special character \r in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, character-encoding, pickle

How comes the symbol `\r` makes pandas bug when reading a csv file?

Example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id','text'])
test.id = [1,2,3]
test.text = ['Foo\rBar','Bar\rFoo','Foo\r\r\nBar']
test.to_csv('temp.csv',index = False)
test2 = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
```

Then the dataframes are as follow:

test:

```
    id  text
0   1   Foo\rBar
1   2   Bar\rFoo
2   3   Foo\r\r\nBar
```

test2:

```
    id      text
0   1       Foo
1   Bar     NaN
2   2       Bar
3   Foo     NaN
4   3       Foo\r\r\nBar
```

Note that adding a `\n` to the text prevent from going to another line. Any idea what's going on? And how to prevent this behavior?

Note thatiIt also prevents from using `pandas.to_pickle` as it corrupts the file. Yielding a file containing the following error:

```
Error! ..\my_pickle.pkl is not UTF-8 encoded
Saving disabled.
See Console for more details.
```

Comment: Use: test.to_csv('temp.csv',index = False,sep=',',line_terminator='\r') , if you want the same output as input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `lineterminator` and `encoding` parameters:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id', 'text'])
test.id = [1, 2, 3]
test.text = ['Foo\rBar', 'Bar\rFoo', 'Foo\r\r\nBar']
test.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False, line_terminator='\n', encoding='utf-8')
test2 = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', lineterminator='\n', encoding='utf-8')
```

test and test2:

```
    id  text
0   1   Foo\rBar
1   2   Bar\rFoo
2   3   Foo\r\r\nBar
```

It works fine for me, but maybe it's only Windows problem (I have MacBook). Also check this [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20353).

Comment: It works fine like this for csv files thank you! Would you have a similar solution for pickle files? As I write and read the files a lot of times, pickle yield faster performances.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have valid csv data all fields containing a newline should be enclosed in double quotes.

The generated csv should look like this:

```
id  text
1   "Foo\rBar"
2   "Bar\rFoo"
3   "Foo\r\r\nBar"
```

or:

```
id  text
1   "Foo
Bar"
2   "Bar
Foo"
3   "Foo


Bar"
```

If the reader only treats `\n` as a newline this will do:

```
id  text
1   Foo\rBar
2   Bar\rFoo
3   "Foo\r\r\nBar"
```

To read the csv data make sure to tell the reader to parse the fields as `quoted` (which could be the default).

The parser might try to autodetect the type of newline in your file (could be `\n`, `\r\n` or even `\r`) and maybe that's why you could have unexpected results if there are combinations of `\r` and `\n` in unquoted fields.